# JQuery not selecting all in from checkbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, client-side-scripting

I cannot seem to get my JQuery working. I have attached my view which has a loop that shows every model in a table format. Each model has a checkbox beside it. The table head also has a checkbox item name/id as checkAll. I have referenced my JQuery script and added my function. I cannot get the function to work, when I click on the checkAll check box nothing happens. I'm extremely new to JQuery and cannot work this one out?

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC_Example2___ADO.Models.Employees>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" >
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#checkAll").click(function () {
            $("input[name='EmployeeIDToDelete']").click(function () {
                if ($("input[name='EmployeeIDToDelete']").length == $("input[name='EmployeeIDToDelete']:checked").length) {
                    $("#checkAll").attr("checked", "checked");
                }
                else {
                    $("#checkAll").removeAttr("checked");
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
<html>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <table align="center" border="1" style="border:ridge;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" name="checkAll" /> </td>
                    <td>Photo</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Gender</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @Html.EditorForModel()
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete Entries" />
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide some rendered HTML to work with? Right off the bat though, none of the table row checkbox click events exist until *after* you've clicked the one in the header. Notice you're adding the click event inside of the handler of another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. You're adding the click handler of the row checkboxes inside the handler of the click on the header checkbox, so there will be no events triggered from the rows.
2. You're improperly using `attr()` when you should probably be using `prop()` (properties vs attributes -- they are two different things).

Here's how I would write this:

```js
$(function() {
  var $checkAll = $('#checkAll');
  var $inputs = $('input[name="EmployeeIDToDelete"]');
  
  $checkAll.click(function() {
    $inputs.prop('checked', this.checked);
  });

  $inputs.change(function() {
      $checkAll.prop('checked', $inputs.length == $inputs.filter(':checked').length);
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" />

<hr />

<input type="checkbox" name="EmployeeIDToDelete" />
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="EmployeeIDToDelete" />
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="EmployeeIDToDelete" />
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="EmployeeIDToDelete" />
<br/>
```

Comment: Or if you hate the maintenace devs `$("#checkAll").prop("checked", $("input[name='EmployeeIDToDelete']").length == $("input[name='EmployeeIDToDelete']:checked").length);`

Answer (score 0):

You're adding click handlers to the `EmployeeIDToDelete` rather than checking/unchecking them, so remove that.
Use `prop` instead of `attr`

```
    $("#checkAll").click(function () {
        //$("input[name='EmployeeIDToDelete']").click(function () {
            if ($("input[name='EmployeeIDToDelete']").length == $("input[name='EmployeeIDToDelete']:checked").length) {
                $("#checkAll").prop("checked", true);
            }
            else {
                $("#checkAll").prop("checked", false);
            }
        //})
    })
```